# How to pass string as object name?

Tags: python, string

**Here's how I finally solved the problem:**

I created two lists, one containing the objects, the other containing the object names (strings). Then I write in the code to make sure that an object and its name are appended to the two lists at the same time. So that I can easily call an object with ObjectList[NameList.index(Name)], similarly with NameList[ObjectList.index(Object)] to call a name.

I don't know if it's the best solution. Maybe I'll find a better way to do this when I know more about python.

Thanks everyone for your help.

---

I've updated my code below.

---

I am trying to make a game that can take in user input, make new objects based on that input, and connect that object with an existing web of objects.

So I have the initial objects: `Adam = Human("Male","God","God")` and `Eve = Human("Female", "God", "God")`

But after `Adam` and `Eve`, I want to create objects like `Josh = Human("Male", Adam, Eve)`, here the attributes of `Josh` becomes one string and two objects, instead of three strings. But if this worked, I can create a web of objects where every obect-child (except Adam and Eve) has object-parents.

If anyone has any suggestions on that, please let me know.

---

I want to pass an user-input string as the name of a new object of a certain class. I can't use `eval()` because it's dangerous. What can I do?

I am new to python3 and creating a little game just for practicing. I've created this class called "Human", and in the game users are supposed to input a name for a new Human.

I haven't tried much as none of the questions I found match my problem. I only know so far that I can't use `eval()` because it might cause trouble if things like `eval("import")` happened.

```
import random

# list of all humans
Humans = []

# creating the class Human
class Human:

    global Humans

    def __init__(self, gender, father, mother):
        self.gender = gender
        self.father = father
        self.mother = mother
        self.canHaveChild = False
        Humans.append(self)

    def growup(self):
        self.canHaveChild = True


Adam = Human("Male", "God", "God")
Eve = Human("Female", "God", "God")
Humans.append(Adam)
Humans.append(Eve)

# creating the class SpiritualHuman
class SpiritualHuman:

    def __init__(self, gend, stparent, ndparent):
        self.stparent = stparent
        self.ndparent = ndparent
        self.gend = gend
        self.canHaveChild = False

# haveChild function
def haveChild(Human1, Human2):

    gender = ""
    gen_pro = random.random()
    if gen_pro < 0.5:
        gender = "Female"
    else:
        gender = "Male"

    if Human1.canHaveChild & Human2.canHavechild:
        if (Human1.gender == "Male") & (Human2.gender == "Female"):
            return Human(gender, Human1, Human2)
        elif (Human1.gender == "Female") & (Human2.gender == "Male"):
            return Human(gender, Human1, Human2)
        elif (Human1.gender == "Male") & (Human2.gender == "Male"):
            return SpiritualHuman("Yang", Human1, Human2)
        else:
            return SpiritualHuman("Yin", Human1, Human2)
    else:
        return "forbidden child"


# a list of all commands
command_list = ["who is the mother of", "who is the father of", "who is the child of", "have child named"]
# user input could be:
# "who is the mother of xxx"
# "who is the father of xxx"
# "who is the child of xxx and xxx"
# "xxx and xxx have child named xxx"



# user input function
def get_input():
    command = input(":")
    comsplit = command.split()
    # check 1st command
    if command_list[0] in command:
        if comsplit[5] in str(Humans):
            print("the mother of", comsplit[5], "is", Humans[str(Humans).index(comsplit[5])].mother())
        else:
            print(comsplit[5], "does not exist")
    # check 2nd command
    elif command_list[1] in command:
        if comsplit[5] in str(Humans):
            print("the father of", comsplit[5], "is", Humans[str(Humans).index(comsplit[5])].father())
        else:
            print(comsplit[5], "does not exist")
    # check 3rd command
    elif command_list[2] in command:
        if comsplit[5] in str(Humans) and comsplit[7] in str(Humans):
            for i in Humans:
                if str(i.father()) in [comsplit[5], comsplit[7]] and str(i.mother()) in [comsplit[5], comsplit[7]]:
                    print(i, "is the child of", comsplit[5], "and", comsplit[7])
                else:
                    print("they don't have a child")
        else:
            print("at least one of the parents you mentioned does not exist")
    # check 4th command
    elif command_list[3] in command:
        if comsplit[0] in str(Humans) and comsplit[2] in str(Humans):
            # here's where the problem is
            # I want to use comsplit[7] as name for a new Human object
            # how should I do it?

        else:
            print("at least one of them is not human")
    elif command == "humans":
        print(str(Humans))
    else:
        print("invalid command. If you need help, please type 'help'")


while(True):
    get_input()
```

I don't know how to avoid errors, but I expect that if the user inputs:
`Adam and Eve have child named Josh`
the result should be that Josh is an object of class Human whose father is Adam and mother is Eve.

Comment: You probably want what is called 'introspection' - I would give more details, but I am not an expert myself. Hopefully this will get your started in the right direction

Comment: `haveChild()` is in the class Human?

Comment: no it's an independent function I defined outside the `class Human`. What I want with this function is like this: `Josh = haveChild(Adam, Eve)`

Comment: what is the `SpiritualHuman`? a class?

Comment: yes, that's for child of two males or females. not related to the problem though

Comment: In Humans.append(self), is Humans a global list? or part of Human Class, also are Human1 and Human2 object of type Human?

Comment: Humans is a list of current humans (objects of Human). I haven't the code here but i basically wrote `Adam = Human("Male", "God", "God");
Eve = Human("Female", "God", "God");
HUMANS = [Adam, Eve]` right after I created "Human" class. So in fact, I would expect the user to input "josh Adam Eve" for a first new human named Josh

Comment: `return Human(...)` you want to return `Human` object?

Comment: yes, so that in the program it should be used like `josh = Human("Male", "Adam", "Eve")`, and that's why i want the user's input (command) to be turned in to something identical to `command[0] = Human(gender, command[1], command[2])` using the `haveChild` function..........wait..I think I know what's wrong here

Answer (score 2):

Use a dict containing your humans, with their names as keys:

```
# global dict, defined at the top of your code
humans = {}

def get_input():
    command = input(":").split()
    if len(command) == 1:
        print(HUMANS) # well, don't know what this one is supposed to be...
    elif len(command) > 1:
        humans[command[1]] = Human(command[1])
        humans[command[2]] = Human(command[2])
        humans[command[0]] = haveChild(humans[command[1]], humans[command[2]])
```

Edit: I just read your comment, can't finish to answer right now, but in short, you must create your father and mother as humans before you can use them, so you need to change something in the way you create them...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm not sure what `Human(command[1])` will give, but isn't command[1] a string as well? for `Human`, the attributes should be gender, father and mother

Comment: I actually wrote two initial humans adam and eve. so the user can take them as first father/mother

Answer (score 1):

The user will enter 2 humans objects with their attributes (gender,father,mother).The 2 objects will be passed to `haveChild()`.Check my code

```
//import radom, it was missing from your code
import random
class Human:

    def __init__(self, gender, father, mother):
        self.gender = gender
        self.father = father
        self.mother = mother
        self.canHaveChild = False

    def growup(self):
        self.canHaveChild = True

def haveChild(obj1, obj2):

    gender = ""
    gen_pro = random.random()
    if gen_pro < 0.5:
        gender = "Female"
    else:
        gender = "Male"

    //obj1.canHaveChild & obj2.canHavechild, was throwing error
    //'Human' object has no attribute 'canHavechild'
    if obj1.canHaveChild and obj2.canHavechild:
        if (obj1.gender == "Male") & (obj2.gender == "Female"):
            return Human(gender, Human1, Human2)
        elif (obj1.gender == "Female") & (obj2.gender == "Male"):
            return Human(gender, mother, father)
        elif (obj1.gender == "Male") & (obj2.gender == "Male"):
            return SpiritualHuman("Yang", Human1, Human2)
        else:
            return SpiritualHuman("Yin", Human1, Human2)
    else:
        return "forbidden child"


def get_input():
    print("Enter Human1 gender,father,mother")
    command = input(":").split()
    human1 = Human(command[0],command[1],command[2])

    print("Enter Human2 gender,father,mother")
    command = input(":").split()
    human2 = Human(command[0],command[1],command[2])

    haveChild(human1,human2)

# the problem above is, command[0] is an immutable (a string), I can't use it 
# directly as the name of a new object

get_input()
```

Comment: hey there, thanks for your answer! Going through your code I suddenly realized that my code is full of bugs..... In fact, what I want is a game that can take user inputs, turn them into objects, and add the objects onto a web of existing objects. I think it should be done in a completely different way than my original code.

Comment: Yes, the code has bugs.Give us a vote for the help.